# Rails Each method Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I know there are question with this title, but none of them solved my problem. So, I want to do this in the `application.html.erb`:

```
<% @food_types.each do |ft| %>
<%= ft.name %>
<%end%>
```

And I have this in my `application_controller.rb`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base    
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  @food_types = FoodType.all
end
```

Here is the migration for the FoodTypes table.

```
class CreateFoodTypes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :food_types do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

What should I do for this error? `undefined method`each' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: where in your application_controller? is it in a helper method?

Comment: Can you post your whole application_controller

Comment: It is the default application_controller.rb.But  here you go

Comment: class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
 
@food_types = FoodType.all
 
end

Comment: You should have posted this in question not in comment

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do this for every single page load rather than an individual controller#action?

Comment: pulled it from the comments up.

Comment: The reason is to make a filter option available in the side bar

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

First check whether you have `food_types` and then iterate it:

In applicationController:

```
before_action :set_food_types

def set_food_types
  @food_types = FoodType.all
end
```

Then, in application.html.erb:

```
<% @food_types.each do |ft| %>
      <%= ft.name %>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: I do have some, i am sure.I have checked from the console

Comment: Wow.Best answeri Thanks.But one question? Since i dont do any method call or anything, why do i have to use a before_filter?Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @HarunTuncay: you do a "method call". To see your food types, you open a page in your app. That is hitting a controller in your app. That constitutes an "action". You need a `before_action` to set auxilliary state for that action.

Comment: As @Sergio Tulentsev said you need a method call to assign value a variable without it you can't assign values to a variable. Hope it helps you & if it solves your problem accept it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to be available to all controllers you should look at doing something like this in your `application_controller.rb`:

```
def food_types
  @food_types ||= FoodType.all
end

helper_method :food_types
```

then change your `each` loop to be:

```
<% food_types.each do |ft| %>
```

Comment: Hmm.It worked,  but what if i had multiple variables, and don't want all of them to be iterated at the same <div>? BTW Thanks.

Comment: I think it is better to write this method in application_helper.rb

Comment: yeah it could go in application_helper, as well.   and @HarunTuncay, well if you have lots of things that are shown on each /every page you would either add them to a helper or a before filter.  I normally memoize them in case they get called multiple times..

Comment: Well, actually this is from a tutorial.And they put 3 variables the way you say it.But in a single method.( 3 variables in "food_types" method.)And they do @variable_name.each do ... and it works.Not food_types.each do